# cocoon 2.1.x to 2.2.0 migration guide

Tags: java, upgrade, apache-cocoon

Can anyone recommend me a good migration guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Cocoon 2.2 Without Tears"](http://www.csparks.com/cocoon/c22without/index.xhtml) is a great article about this upgrade:

> This page describes an unusual way of using cocoon 2.2. Consequently, it is best appreciated by former users of cocoon 2.1 or people who have already come up against frustrations using 2.2.

See also:

- ["New in 2.2: Migrating 2.1 components"](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/1420_1_1.html)
- ["Forms Migration guide"](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/forms/1.0/1351_1_1.html) and ["AJAX Migration Guide"](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/ajax/1.0/1350_1_1.html)